# Ionic 2 : Change a sass variable dynamically

Tags: angular, sass, ionic2

I use Ionic 2 and I want to change variable on my scss file dynamically.

I have this variable :

```
$tab-image : url('http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg');
```

I want to change the url by another in a **.ts** file to finaly change the picture. I want to change it in a component or a provider.

More over, I want to replace the url by somethink like :

```
data:[my-file-type]';base64,[my-file-content]
```

**Q :** It is possible ?

**Q :** How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SASS is a **pre**-processor, meaning that once it has been processed (before your web page is rendered), you cannot re-process it.

*Are you using your `$tab-image` as a `background-image`?*

You may use [NgClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) in order to dynamically add/remove an additional css class to your component/node. This one having different styles, overriding any value (like `background-image`).

You can use `url(data:image/png;base64,[...]` in CSS. Be careful, IE7 and 8 don't support this syntax (IE8 does, but with a very tiny content). (NB: `image/png` is for the sake of the example. Use the appropriate MIME type according to your file).

Comment: Oh ok ! 
I want to modify a tab-icon in my tab button. I create this variable to have a custom icon. 
When my user change, I want to set this icon with his profile picture. I don't know if NgClass can help me because I touche specifics class.